# Object oriented design - Designing business rules

Tags: object-oriented

I have trouble designing classes that reflect different business behaviors/rules. An example to explain my case:

```
- a tour has a departure
- a departure may be a guaranteed departure
if a departure is guaranteed:
    - a guaranteed departure may have a date that, starting from that date:
    * departure cannot be cancelled by tour agency for any reason
    * before that date in can be cancelled
    * but it may not have a date indicator, which means departure can't be cancelled
else:
   - departure can be cancelled anytime by agency for any reason
```

What's the correct way to design classes in such scenarios?

- A simple boolean field (cancellable) and simple Date field (cancellableBefore)  in Departure class

when cancellable == true and cancellableBefore == null **=>** always cancellable

when cancellable == true and cancellableBefore != null **=>** cancellable if now < cancellableBefore

...

and so on...

or is there a more OO answer to this?

Answer (score 3):

To make this more OO, create three classes that represent your departure and isolate the logic to determine if it can be canceled there. The classes inherit from a common interface IDeparture with a method canBeCanceledOn that takes a datetime indicating the point in time when a cancellation is attempted.

Next, create three classes for your departures. RegularDeparture can be cancelled at any time and will always return true for the canBeCanceledOn. FixedDeparture would be a fixed departure that cannot be canceled and always return false for canBeCanceledOn. CancellableUntilSetDateDeparture would use logic to determine if the date up to which the departure can be canceled is before the provided cancellation attempt date.

This way you have classes that are responsible for one thing only (represent a type of departure) and you can add additional departure types as needed and 'plug' them into Tours.

Comment: But Departure classes have common fields, such as when that departure is happening. In this case, shoud IDeparture be an abstract class?

Comment: If there is common logic or common fields to them then yes, that is a good case to make an abstract base class for it.

Comment: Should the IDeparture interface have a cancel() method which throws exception for FixedDeparture, or should IDeparture be further extended to ICancellableDeparture, INonCancellableDeparture... and so on?

Comment: @Reek: As you have `canBeCancelledOn` that can be used to see if cancelling would work, there is nothing wrong with having a `cancel` method that throws if `canBeCancelledOn` returned false.